# Do these followings hold ?$ (12)(34)=(134)(132) $ and $ (12345)=(123)(145)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $G=A_5\;$ and let $\;\{1,2,3,4,5\}=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$
>
> Verify that $$(ab)(cd)=(acd)(acb) , (abcde)=(abc)(ade)$$
>
> Hence show that $G=\big < X\big >,\quad $  where $X=\{x\in G| x^3=1\}$

If I understood the question correctly, I am supposed to calculate the following ones:
$$(12)(34)=(134)(132)  $$  ,equivalently
$$\binom{12345}{21345}\binom{12345}{12435}=\binom{12345}{32415}\binom{12345}{31245} $$  ,when I calculate LHS & RHS ,I get this:

$$ \binom{12345}{21435}=\binom{12345}{43215}$$ which is absurd, since these are not equal. Similarly, when I compute the second one $(12345)=(123)(145)$

I get:
$$\binom{12345}{23451}=\binom{12345}{43152}$$ which is also incorrect. Where do I make mistake?

Edit:Permutations are applied from left to right

Comment: You're supposed to prove the more general identities in $a,b,c,d,e$, not just for the permutations you highlighted.

Comment: I did this way since it says let $\;\{1,2,3,4,5\}=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$  How one should interpret this phrase then?

Comment: The sets of equal, yes, but the order of the elements is not fixed.

Comment: oh yes, okay. I see now

Comment: So, if it is general, why does not hold for the choices I made ?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Because the question, as stated, is wrong.

Comment: It's from Rose's "A Course on Group Theory" @DuncanRamage

Comment: @LeylaAlkan Then Rose made a mistake. It happens. If it's an active course, or if it's a book whose author is still alive and active, I'd see if I could find an email address for them and tell them the mistake. Afterwards, I'd keep my eyes out for more mistakes. If this becomes a pattern, I'd start exploring other options for learning group theory.

Comment: @LeylaAlkan You should also see if the author keeps an errata around. It may be possible that they are already aware of this mistake, and have it corrected somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the RHS is wrong, if you apply the permutations from left to right.
In the $1^{st}$ calculation from $(134)(132)$ I get
 $$1\to3\to2\\ 
2\to 1\\  
3\to 4 \\
4\to 1\to 3 \\
5\to 5$$
so $(134)(132) = (12)(34)$ as you wanted.

Similarly for the second calculation.

The final result, as I expect you know comes from showing that $A_5= \mathrm gp\langle (12)(34), (12345) \rangle $

Comment: It gets complicated with each answer :)

Comment: This is wrong. $1 \rightarrow 3 \rightarrow 4$, for starters.

Comment: What do you mean by starters? Is there any other way to compute?@DuncanRamage

Comment: @DuncanRamage my assumption, as stated in my answer, is that we are applying the permutations from left to right. Under that assumption you are wrong. because you are applying them right to left.

Comment: @StephenMeskin You're right. The question is correct if you apply them from left to right, but this is highly nonstandard. Permutations are functions, and functions act on the left.

Comment: I have found similar nonstandard composition of functions in this book. I guess Rose likes to use nonstandard things :)

Comment: @DuncanRamage I have always (for many decades) applied permutations on the right but I not heard anyone call me nonstandard except my family of non-mathematicians. I have also been known to apply functions on the right!!!

Comment: For second part, you mean (12345)(12345)(12345)=1 but I found it's (14253) @StephenMeskin

Comment: What does gp mean here?@StephenMeskin

Comment: @LeylaAlkan "Group generated by"

Comment: I used $\mathrm {gp} \langle a,b. ... \rangle$ to mean the group generated by $\{a, b.\, ...\}$. That notation may not be standard but it's a habit of mine from working in areas where the same elements belong to groups and rings or other things..  I'm not certain what you mean by the "$2^{nd}$ part but the first pieces of your question show that certain elements of $A_5$ are in the group generated by $X$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like what you're trying to verify is wrong. (I mean the question itself.)

We have $(ab)(cd)a=(ab)a=b$ but $(acd)(acb)a=(acd)c=d$.

Comment: It's unlikely I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the question is definitely wrong. What it should probably say is $(ad)(cb) = (acd)(acb)$ and $(adebc) = (abc)(ade)$, or some equivalent permutation of the symbols. Once you've done this, the second part should follow easily. Every element of $A_5$ is a disjoint product of cycles. They can be two 2-cycles, one 3-cycle, or one 5-cycle, by considering how many elements can be permuted, and by considering the parity of the elements. The middle case is obviously part of $\langle X \rangle$, and the first and last are part of $\langle X \rangle$ by the calculations we've just performed.

EDIT: As Stephen Meskin points out in his answer, this is correct. However, you need to follow the convention that permutations are read from left to right for this to be true. This convention is highly nonstandard, as permutations are functions, and functions act on the left.

Comment: I thought the same, for example I know that (abcd) could be written as (ad)(ac)(ab)

Comment: Why does x have to be the product of disjoint 2- and 4- cycles?

Comment: @LeylaAlkan That part of my answer was mistaken. I've removed it for now; I'll post a corrected version later.

Comment: @LeylaAlkan I've now updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

$(ab)(cd)$ defines $a$ and $b$ are swapped, then $c$ and $d$ are swapped, right?

Then $(acd)(acb)$ is:

- $a$ is replaced with $c$, then $c$ is replaced with $b$ (so eventually $a$ gets replaced with $b$);
- $b$ is not touched initially, but then replaced with $a$ (hence $a$ and $b$ get swapped);
- $c$ gets replaced with $d$ and not touched anymore,
- and $d$ is replaced with $a$ which then gets replaced with $c$ (hence $c$ and $d$ get swapped).

If that's correct then you must have made some mistake.